# Select all columns but change a column to string

Tags: sql, sql-server

In `Sql`, if I want to fetch all columns from a table then I would write `select * from <table name>`. However let say there is a column called `XYZ` and type is `numeric`. However I want to fetch all columns but change that `XYZ` column to `sting`, then how should one proceed?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: List out all columns.  Do the conversion explicitly.

Comment: `SELECT *` should almost never be used in production code; it is fine for "developer" queries and troubleshooting, but for day to day operations SELECTs should always have the fields retrieved explicitly listed, and preferably unused fields omitted. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639964/4104224) for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the other columns individually, and `CAST(xyz AS NVARCHAR)`

```
SELECT foo, bar, CAST(xyz AS NVARCHAR)
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it without either specifying all the columns or duplicating the one you want to convert.

```sql
SELECT *, CAST(XYZ as varchar) as XYZ_String
FROM <table>
```

Comment: With this I am getting below error '(DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=*;select ;NULL, DRIVER=4.19.26)'. However if I remove '*' then result is fine

Comment: I don't know much about DB2. The question was tagged as SQL Server, and I'm pretty confident this would work there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(column AS NVARCHAR(25)) AS xyz_string 
FROM Table
```